# upper bound for $ \mathbb{E}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[1/X] $

Tags: probability-theory

This is part of problem 2.6.46 in Shiryaev's 'problems in probability'.
Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values in the interval $[a,b]$ for some $0<a<b<\infty$. Prove that $$ \mathbb{E}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}\!\left[\dfrac{1}{X}\right]\leq \dfrac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}. $$

**Edit**

I study alone from the books of Shiryaev: 'probability' and 'problems in probability'. After reading section 2.6 I know what are Random Variables, Lebesgue Integral, Expectation. I also know the inequalities of Chebyshev, Cauchy-Bunyakovskii, Jensen, Lyapunov, Holder and Minkowski, but I don't see how any of these help me with this question.

I might be missing something very simple, but for now I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Right, you "want to show" this, but what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the remark. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: No, I see only the statement of a problem with no personal input.

Comment: Ok, added some background. Thank you for your patience. As you probably realize I'm a newbie here.

Comment: The LHS achieves its max of RHS for $X$ symmetric on $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: For any $X$ that puts mass in $(a,b)$, you can spread it out to the sides while keeping $E(X)$ constant and increasing $E(1/X)$. So you are left with optimization over one Bernoulli parameter and $1/2$ is the extremizer.

Comment: Thanks A.S. I understand your reasoning but would still like to see a proof.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this is 'off-topic'?